# jQuery to copy value in select drop down to all drop down

Tags: jquery

I have a form that loops over the database and displays the form to the user.  The user is supposed to change the drop down value to Add Duplicate or Move but in many cases, they will all be the same.  so, I'd like to give them a "Copy Down" feature where they can click on an icon.  This will fire a function to get the value of the selected input name (just in front of the icon in the same table cell (td) and set the other items in the list to the same value.  ID's are unique and I thought I could get use $('#id').val() to get the value but even that isn't working.

```
            <tr id="row_653"> <-- this value increments -->
            <td>xtipi208_c_dl8453</td>
            <td>Dalllas</td>
            <td>ibm</td>
            <td>SLPAR on p570</td>
            <td>2012-04-15</td>
            <td>dl8453</td>
            <td>mt1933</td>
            <td><select name="systemAction_653" id="SystemAction_653" class="systemAction">
                    <option value="0">Action Required</option>
                    <option value="copy">Add Dup</option>
                    <option value="move">Move</option>
                </select>
                <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-copy vtip replicate" id="select_resource_653" title="Copy this value down the list." style="float: right;" name="systemAction" systemid="653" cntr="13"></span></td>
        </tr>
```

and here is the JS I'm working with:

```
$('.replicate').live("click",function(){
    var nm=$(this).attr('name');
    var cntr=$(this).attr('cntr');
    var systemID=$(this).attr('systemID');
    var vl=$(this).parent().prev().find("select").val();

    //  alert(nm + ' ' + cntr + ' ' + systemID + ' ' + vl);  //for vl, I'm getting undefined

    $('[name="'+nm+'"][systemID="'+ systemID + '"]').each(function() {
    if ($(this).attr("cntr") >= cntr) 
        $(this).parent().prev().find("select").val(vl);
      });
});
```

Comment: All data returned by `.attr()` is in string format. Change you comparizon to compare numbers by converting the values.

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying.

Comment: Sorry. I mean that you are trying to compare the `cntr` attributes like numbers, but they are returned as strings. To do so, you have to cast them as numbers before (using `Number(cntr)` for example). Leme nkow if it worked, so I can post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to know for sure but it may be as simple as this:

```
$('table').on("click", "button.copy_down", function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    var vl = $this.siblings("select.systemAction").val();
    $this.closest("tr").nextAll().find("select.systemAction").val(vl);
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uM6Mh/2/)

Comment: Based on your jsFiddle, this is exactly what I'm looking for!  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

From what I gather, you have a bunch of `<select>`s on a page, which can have the same selected value, right? Instead of forcing the user to select the same element for each `<select>` you want to implement a button that would set them all to the same selected value, correct?

If so, then this does the trick:

http://jsfiddle.net/TS3gB/8/

Of course it will not fit seamlessly into the existing codebase, but should provide the method and insight for you to modify it to fit your needs.

If I misunderstood your question let me know and I will try to help further and/or remove this answer.

Comment: This does what I'm looking for EXCEPT lets say there are 20 selects.  The first 5 might need to be a different value so the user marks those as needed but 6-20 will be the same value so the "propogate" button like in your example will need to populate only from 6-20, skipping the first 5.  I believe I can get teh loop to work with your example, I just wanted to clarify the slight difference in what I'm looking for and what you provided.  I need to step away for a bit but I"ll be back later toonight.  Thanks,

Comment: You will just need to do some `id` or `class` trickery. Ill update the jsfiddle where the buttons only fill certain `select`s

Comment: edited : http://jsfiddle.net/TS3gB/3/ (seems its been too long to just edit previous comment) edit2: added comments

Comment: Oh god, I can't stop editing it! http://jsfiddle.net/TS3gB/8/ Ill stop, I promise.

Comment: Don't stop editing!  LOL. If I provided more code, would that help?

Comment: You were on the right track but Beetroot's answer was what I needed. Thank you very much for working with me.